# How to make Firefox startup faster in GDB

Tags: debugging, testing, firefox, automated-tests, gdb

I have a large number of HTML files to debug. I wrote a python GDB script and call `gdb ./path/to/firefox` and open each of the HTML files within Firefox, then run the script to do what I want. The problem is this process is super slow. I am wondering is there a faster way to do this.

I noticed that everything else is fairly fast except the point after gdb outputs the following:

```
$ gdb ../firefox-63.0.3/objdir-ff-dbg/dist/bin/firefox
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ../firefox-63.0.3/objdir-ff-dbg/dist/bin/firefox...done.
(gdb) set args file:///home/ug16zy2/test.html 
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ug16zy2/firefox-63.0.3/objdir-ff-dbg/dist/bin/firefox file:///home/ug16zy2/test.html 
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
```

Then I need to wait for a long time (around 20 seconds) until it outputs the next line:

```
Loading JavaScript value pretty-printers; see js/src/gdb/README.
If they cause trouble, type: disable pretty-printer .* SpiderMonkey
SpiderMonkey unwinder is disabled by default, to enable it type:
    enable unwinder .* SpiderMonkey
```

What is GDB doing and how can I avoid whichever is taking such a long time?

PS: I need to use GDB because I want to stop the process when a specific line in JS code is executed. Unfortunately the line is inside a callback registered with an event listener. The problem boils down to stopping Firefox when an event listener is triggered AND its callback function finishes execution. (If there is any other alternative that can achieve the same thing, pls let me know :) Many thanks!)

Comment: Is there anything in your `~/.gdbinit` file that can cause the running process to stop and start repeatedly, such as breakpoints, watchpoints, catchpoints, trace, collect, handle, record, etc.?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I have ```add-auto-load-safe-path /home/ug16zy2/firefox-63.0.3/.gdbinit``` and ```set auto-load safe-path /``` in ```~/.gdbinit```. Inside ```/home/ug16zy2/firefox-63.0.3/.gdbinit```, there are only definitions of more customized commands. Commenting the first line out does not speed it up.

Answer (score 4):

> What is GDB doing and how can I avoid whichever is taking such a long time?

There are a few things that are happening here:

1. GDB reads debug info for `firefox` binary itself, then runs it.
2. When `firefox` loads shared libraries, the dynamic loader notifies GDB about them, and GDB reads debug info for them.
3. When `libpthread` is loaded, GDB loads `libthread_db` and sets it up to notify GDB about thread creation and destruction events (this is when `Using host libthread_db` message is printed).
4. `firefox` initializes itself.
5. `firefox` starts actually running (doing useful work).

You can see more of GDB's actions with `set verbose on`.

I am *guessing* that `firefox` binary is *directly* linked with only a few shared libraries, and `dlopen`s the majority of required libraries after it starts running (i.e. during step 4 above).

I am further guessing that some of the libraries are large, and it takes a while to load debug info for them.

If, after `set verbose on`, you see that above guesses are correct, you can disable auto-loading of symbols for shared libraries with `set auto-solib-add off`. You can then add *just* the libraries that you need symbols for (if any) with `sharedlibrary libfoo` command.

**Update:**

> It is actually taking a majority of the time loading symbol from libxul.so. However I guess I need it in order to debug Firefox. Is there a way of preloading those symbols or avoiding loading this library every time?

I thought it would help to turn your script "inside out" -- to start a single GDB session, and execute repeated `run` commands with different arguments from inside that session.

But I am not sure that would actually help: last time I worked on GDB, it discarded and re-read all the DSOs on inferior (being debugged) program restart.

If GDB still does that, the only solutions I can think of are:

1. Try using LLDB instead. It may be faster, or it may work with "inside out" script.
2. Build `libxul.so` with less debug info (i.e. add `-g` *only* for the files that you need for your debugging, and build the rest of the files with `-g0`).

Comment: I checked. It is actually taking a majority of the time loading symbol from ```libxul.so```. However I guess I need it in order to debug Firefox. Is there a way of preloading those symbols or avoiding loading this library every time?

Comment: Thanks! Yes gdb re-read all DSOs on inferior program restart. :(

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer states, the problem is that gdb is naive about debuginfo caching.  And, because libxul is so large, it takes a noticeable amount of time.

If you have gdb 8.3 or later, you can fix this somewhat by using the new `index-cache` feature.  To use it just type:

```
(gdb) set index-cache on
```

... or put it in your `~/.gdbinit` for best effect.

The index cache will write an index for the debuginfo to a file in a cache directory (type `show index-cache directory` to see where).  This should speed up re-reading.

Note that nothing prunes the index cache right now -- this is the major drawback.  So, you will want to occasionally delete old files here.  This lack of pruning is one reason that the cache isn't enabled by default.